# Neo4j: Create index for nodes with same property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with many different elements but every element has a property "ID". Now i would like to

CREATE INDEX ON :anyType(ID)

How can i trigger the index creation for any type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CREATE INDEX ON` takes a label, and cannot be called without the label (nor can it be called with multiple labels). So you'd have to execute this for each label type.

That is, you can't run:

```
CREATE INDEX(ID)
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX ON:*(ID)
```

You need to run:

```
CREATE INDEX ON:label(ID)
```

Comment: Or you create an overarching label and index for `:Node(ID)` or `:Entity(ID)`

Comment: So does the `:Node` label reference all nodes in the graph? And if so, is `:Entity`  nodes and relationships?

Comment: @Joe No. Michael was suggesting that you add a global label to all of your nodes, in addition to any specialized labels you have for specific subsets of notice. There is no default label applied to new nodes.